# How to Sum Price of Array of Products with their quantities in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I am trying to calculate the sum of the price of multiple products with their quantities.
The request is:

```
[{"product_id": 14, "quantity": 1}, {"product_id": 18, "quantity": 1}, {"product_id": 15, "quantity": 1}]
```

I get product_ids [14,18,15] from the above array and with whereIn find the sum:

```
Product::whereIn('id', $product_ids)->sum("prices");
```

How can I also consider the quantities while calculating the sum, I can do it by foreach but is there any other solution?

Comment: Multiply the quantities by **what** not the `product_id` surely

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I edited the question, thanks :)

Comment: This needs some more information. Is this an Order of specific Products? What does that JSON represent?

Comment: Well, it is the request and I am trying to create and order, so I get, product IDs and quantities from the request, and I need to calculate the sum.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'request' looks like json so first we have to transform it to an object or array using `json_decode`.

```php
$json = '[{"product_id": 14, "quantity": 1}, {"product_id": 18, "quantity": 1}, {"product_id": 15, "quantity": 1}]';

$collection = collect(json_decode($json));

$totalPrice = Product::query()
    ->select('id', 'price')
    ->whereIn('id', $collection->pluck('product_id')
    ->cursor() // we don't really need to load the models in memory.
    ->reduce(function ($accumulated, $product) use ($collection) { // reduce the collection to a single value
        return $accumulated + ( $product->price * $collection->firstWhere('product_id', $product->id)->quantity );
    }, 0); // set initial $accumulated is 0
```

Or using shorthand closures

```php
$totalPrice = Product::query()
    ->select('id', 'price')
    ->whereIn('id', $collection->pluck('product_id')
    ->cursor()
    ->reduce(fn($a, $p) => $a + ( $p->price * $collection->firstWhere('product_id', $p->id)->quantity ), 0);
```